# How to stop losing values after postback?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with textboxes where the user can enter information in the textbox and it will create the row on the grid based on the values from the textboxes. But the button that adds the row to the grid is causing a postback so I lose all my values in the code behind.

Code for Grid and textboxes:

```
<div style="padding-top:20px">
                <fieldset class="groupbox_nohide" >    
                    <div style="width:100%">
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="udpCosts" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <asp:GridView  style="width:75%;float:left"  
                                    ID="gvCosts" 
                                    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                                    CssClass="tblResults" 
                                    runat="server" 
                                    OnRowDataBound="gvCosts_RowDataBound"                             
                                    DataKeyField="ID" 
                                    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                    allowpaging="false"
                                    AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE">
                                    <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                                    <Columns>       
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreditorCode" HeaderText="Creditor Code"></asp:BoundField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCreateCost" />
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpdateCost" /> 
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel> 
                        <div id="divAddEditPiece" runat="server">      
                <table>
                    <tr class="tblResults">
                        <td class="header" style="border-right:2px">
                            Creditor A/C<label style="color:Red"></label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tblResults">

                        <td class="tblAddDetail" style="border-right:2px">
                            <a style="float:left;width:16px;height:16px;margin-right:0px;left:0px;top:1px" title="Pick from list..." class="iconSearch" id="btnAddDetailCreditor"></a>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCreditorID" runat="server"  />
                            <input type="text" id="txtAddEditCreditorCode" class="lookuppopup" style="text-transform:uppercase;width:80px" runat="server"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="tblAddDetail" colspan="15">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCreateCost" OnClientClick="tinyMCE.triggerSave(false, true);" runat="server" style="float:left;width:25px" CssClass="btnNewSmall">Add</asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                    </tr>     
                </table>
            </div>
```

Then in the javascript code the hiddenfield and textbox get set their values:

```
$('#<%= hfCreditorID.ClientID %>').val(result.ID);
$('#<%= txtAddEditCreditorCode.ClientID %>').val(result.AccountCode);
```

But as soon as I click on the create button the values get set back to blank so in the code behind the hiddenfield and textbox is always blank:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
     btnCreateCost.Click += new EventHandler(btnCreateCost_Click);
}
protected void btnCreateCost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int  tmpCredID;

        bool valid = true;
        string ErrMsg = "Error: The following fields cannot be empty:";

        if (!int.TryParse(hfCreditorID.Value, out tmpCredID))
        {
            valid = false;
            ErrMsg += "<br />Creditor Code";
        }
}
```

How can I pass these values to the code behind?

Comment: @S.Akbari sorry I don't really understand what I need to do. What do I need to bind?

Comment: Just off hand, the controls (hiddenfield, textbox) are outside of the update panel and thus outside of the asyncpostback...try moving the controls inside the updatepanel contenttemplate tags...

Comment: @Dave I tired that but they are still coming back as blank is the code behind

Comment: @user123456789 Just to confirm as well, you encased the entire set of controls including the linkbutton AND also added in the asyncpostback trigger for that control for the click event as well (and taking a closer look, your asyncpostback triggers don't have events defined...ie. EventName="Click")?

Comment: @Dave yes I moved the whole `divAddEditPiece` section inside the updatepanel. What do you mean they don't have any events? The function `OnInit` has the EventHandler

Comment: @user123456789 within the UpdatePanel Triggers element, you need to have  `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCreateCost" EventName="Click" />` remember, it's an async postback. your init just ties the event to the control. could just as easily do `<asp:LinkButton ID="btnCreateCost" OnClick="btnCreateCost_Click" OnClientClick="tinyMCE.triggerSave(false, true);" runat="server" style="float:left;width:25px" CssClass="btnNewSmall">Add</asp:LinkButton>` and remove the OnInit

Comment: @Dave ok I added `EventName="Click"` but the hiddenfield and textbox are still coming in as blank on the code behind

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125428/discussion-between-dave-and-user123456789).

Answer (score 0):

Add a click event for your btnCreateCost in jquery. Then you can use an ajax post to do your work.

```
$('#btnCreateCost').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "yourwebmethodurl",
        data: "{'parametername':'" + parametervalue + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(mes);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    })
});
```

Here is the page where the example came from. I took two post and put it together. https://forums.asp.net/t/2047043.aspx?Stop+Page+Post+Back+using+Javascript+jQuery